# importing .sql file to phpmyadmin/workbench using jsp and servlet

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to code an importing .sql file in phpmyadmin or workbench and also exporting a database (.sql file) inside a jsp without opening the phpmyadmin or workbench?

if it's possible, can u please kindly give me a link or examples maybe...

Comment: and why would you do that from a JSP ? JSPs are meant for rendering data to display

Comment: so it's not possible? I just want to make it for our proponent convenience

Comment: it is but this is an out and out bad practice

Comment: oh okay... but I just want to configure the import about the primary duplicate

Comment: and what is that primary duplicate?

Comment: i mean primary key duplicate